Easy to copy Python code snippets with doctest enabled
When adding doctests to my markdown, I have to write something like

```python
>>>import numpy
>>>np.sum([1, 2])
3
```

This works fine with doctest. However, when I render the markdown page on Github, it's difficult to copy/paste the example, as the interactive Python parts (such as >>>) are still there.
For instance, on the Python documentation for doctest itself: https://docs.python.org/3/library/doctest.html#how-are-docstring-examples-recognized one can click the button 'Hide the prompts and output', which makes copying easy. Can the same be achieved in Github markdown rendering?

This is not possible in GitHub markdown. As a workaround, you could provide both the doctest version and a plain version of the code.
If you really need a more interactive solution, you could consider a static site generator (e.g., Jekyll or MkDocs with custom plugins) or JavaScript to toggle visibility of prompts and outputs. The downside of this solution would that it requires hosting the documentation by yourself outside of GitHub's native Markdown rendering.
